# bootstrap 3 - one row is spacing the content from the element of other row

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, twitter-bootstrap-3

When developing the html of a dashboard I'm stuck with the following scenario:

The dashboard have a header that have some content like a title and the username with edit and logout buttons.

Next it have vertical aside menu and on its side the content to be showed, my problem is that the menu is being spaced from the edge of the browser, I've checked for custom margins, but I don't have it, so its too strange.

I'm posting here the jsfiddle with the code, any help is appreciated.

```
[The Code][1]


  [1]: https://jsfiddle.net/sumxocp6/
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow! Questions seeking debugging help must include the shortest code necessary to reproduce it **in the question itself.** NB - **Please don't abuse the code blocks to get around this requirement**.

Answer (score 0):

The proper syntax for a Grid Row in Bootstrap is `.row` not `.row-fluid`.  If you change your code to reflect the correct syntax the grid spacing functions as expected in Bootstrap.

Comment: I was using .container > .row > /col-* but i tried to use the *-fluid to verify if it corrects the problem, but no solution

Comment: You may wish to update your Fiddle then, it still uses `.row-fluid` instead of `.row`.  I believe `.row-fluid` was valid syntax back in v2.x